# Non-primitive property (struct) is not serialized in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to serialize a non-primitive property (struct) within an entity and Entity Framework just does not serialize it.

UPDATE: Reformulating the question and sharing the affected code.

```
public class ClassToPersist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ValueWrapper SomeValue { get; set; }
}

public struct ValueWrapper
{
    public Guid Value { get; set; }
}
```

And in my `OnModelCreating` function I just declare:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeClass>();
```

The result of this is not a compile, nor runtime error, Entity Framewrok just skips serializing the `SomeValue` field.
Please note that `ValueWrapper` is a struct. If I convert it to a class, it works properly by "flattening" the data inside it.

Is it that "custom" structs can't be serialized? Is it a limitation of the library or maybe there's a way to specify the serialization convention to use in this case?

Comment: Can you please provide the code which is throwing compile time error?

Comment: What type? This question contains no useful detail information. If it's your own class, you'll have to serialize it yourself. Databases only know simple types. Complex types usually translate to actual tables.